# Как просмотреть отрезанную часть среза preserveAspectRatio xMinYMin

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

Я использую

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 902" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
```

Я хочу, чтобы мой SVG не растягивался при изменении размера окна.

SVG полностью заполняет мою веб-страницу в развернутом окне, и я хочу позволить пользователю просматривать все в SVG (даже если пользователь должен прокрутить, чтобы просмотреть его).

Но проблема в том, что когда я изменяю размер окна, оно отрезает часть переполнения и не возможно его просмотреть.

Есть ли способ позволить пользователю просматривать часть переполнения с помощью прокрутки или другого типа подхода (кроме использования preserveAspectRatio), чтобы сделать это?

Ниже часть кода CSS, который я использую:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body,
svg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#Layer_1 {
    display: block;
}
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to view the sliced part of preserveAspectRatio xMinYMin slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62826430/7394871) от участника  [@Raymond Chong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10624534/raymond-chong).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62826430/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Как я уже писал в комментариях, вы можете сделать это, изменив значение атрибута viewBox. Далее следует очень простой пример, в котором вы используете ползунок для изменения значения viewBox:

```js
itr.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  let val = itr.value;
  theSVG.setAttribute("viewBox",`${val} 0 1920 902`)
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<input id="itr" type="range" min="-1000" max="1000" value="0">
<svg id="theSVG" viewBox="0 0 1920 902" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
<polyline points="-500,50 2500,400 -700,850 -500,50" />  
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How to view the sliced part of preserveAspectRatio xMinYMin slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62828493/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>